# How to traverse through keys and values simultaneously in javascript (react native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to print keys and values inside jsx of react native, I get keys but also I want value simultaneously for that particular key.

```js
{
  Object.keys(Data).map((key, index) => {
    return (
      <View style= {{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View>
          <Text>{ key }</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: `Object.entries(Data).map(([key,value]) =>` or else `{Data[key]}`.

Comment: I got from the second but i didn't understood that object.keys will contain only the array of keys so Data array will contain keys so how it gets the values?

Comment: What's in a name, right? `Object.keys` gives only keys, and `Object.values` gives only values, and `Object.entries` gives both in an array. But anyway, if you have the key, you can just do `Data[key]` to get the corresponding value too.

Comment: ok got it thanks you

Comment: Check the documentation for Object.entries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries